# Crear comando en linux local y hacer una acción en servidor

Tags: linux, servidor, terminal

Deseo crear un solo comando el cual haga una conexión en un servidor con ssh y luego se mueva a un directorio y luego ejecute una línea que contiene un `archivo.py`, es posible esto desde mi local? En el servidor no puedo porque no me permite acceder con `sudo`.

Ejemplo de lo que deseo lograr:

```
$ miComando
```

Lo que debería hacer mi comando:

```
- ssh usuario@servidor
- (pedirá contraseña)
- cd /home/usr/dir/
- python manage.py get_all.py
- (devolverá una respuesta)
```

¿Es posible?

Comment: Es en inglés, pero tal vez este es lo que busca: https://www.shellhacks.com/ssh-execute-remote-command-script-linux/

Answer (score 6):

Primero, tienes que montar el ssh sin contraseña. [Es muy simple](https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/):

1. Crea tu llave

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa
   ```

   Cuando te pide donde guardarla, dale al <kbd>enter</kbd> para acceptar el valor por defecto (`$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa`). Y cuando te pide la frase de contraseña, déjala vacía ([cosa que no es muy peligrosa](https://serverfault.com/q/142959) al menos que trabajes en una maquina super abierta).
2. Si no existe, crea el directorio `~/.ssh` en el servidor:

   ```
   ssh tuUsuario@elServidor mkdir ~/.ssh
   ```
3. Copia la llave al servidor:

   ```
   ssh-copy-id tuUsuario@elServidor
   ```

   O, si tu sistema no tiene el `ssh-copy-id`, hazlo manualmente:

   ```
   cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh tuUsuario@elServidor 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
   ```

   En este caso, también tienes que poner los permisos correctos:

   ```
   ssh tuUsuario@elServidor "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
   ```

Ahora que tienes todo esto listo, puedes conectarte al servidor sin llave. Entonces, puedes simplemente hacer:

```
ssh usuario@servidor 'cd /home/usr/dir/ && python manage.py get_all.py'
```

Y si necesitas la respuesta en un variable:

```
variable=$(ssh usuario@servidor 'cd /home/usr/dir/ && python manage.py get_all.py')
```

---

Si no quieres montar el acceso sin llave, puedes usar `sshpass` que te permite hacer:

```
sshpass -p "$password"  usuario@servidor 'cd /home/usr/dir/ && python manage.py get_all.py'
```

O puedes tener la llave en el variable `$SSHPASS`, y después hacer:

```
sshpass -e usuario@servidor 'cd /home/usr/dir/ && python manage.py get_all.py'
```

Pero es mucho mejor usar el primer método en vez de `sshpass`.